# CakePHP 2.1 call plugin model in main controller

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.1

I am using a plugin, So i have defined some functions in model of plugin. So how to call those in main controller but not in plugin controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
public $uses = array('ModelName1', "SomeothermodelName", 'DebugKit.ToolbarAccess');
```

This will load:

1. "ModelName1" and "SomeothermodelName" from app/Model - thus the application itself.
2. The "ToolbarAccess.php" from Plugin/DebugKit/Model via "**DebugKit.ToolbarAccess**"

The bolded part (**DebugKit.ToolbarAccess**) is the so-called [plugin syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-plugin-syntax).

Now in your controller you should be able to access the ToolbarAccess model like this (example):

```
$this->ToolbarAccess->find('list');
```

You can also try `$this->loadModel(DebugKit.ToolbarAccess);` from the controller.

Comment: Sabev: I have included that $uses variable.. still i am getting these errors.                                                          Error: The application is trying to load a file from the calender plugin,Error: Make sure your plugin calender is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded

Comment: You can also try $this->loadModel(DebugKit.ToolbarAccess); from the controller.How does this go?